# calculate percentage and grade from input file in awk

Tags: awk, scripting

I have a file which contains sample data as follows:

```
Student Name,Assignment Type,Assignment Number,Total Earned Points,Total Possible Points
Chelsey,Final,FINAL,82,100
Chelsey,Survey,WS,5,5
Sam,Homework,H01,19,100
Sam,Homework,H02,82,100
```

I want to calculate the weighted grade (total earned points divided by total possible points) for each student and output a list of students, their grade as a percentage and a letter grade. Letter grade scale is as follows:

```
A = 90 >= grade <= 100
B = 80 >= grade < 90
C = 70 >= grade < 80
D = 60 >= grade < 70
E = grade < 60
```

Output format:

```
Name    Percent Letter
Chelsey XX.XX   *
Sam     YY.YY   *
```

How do I achieve this in awk? Currently, I have a column average script.

```
awk '
    NR>1{
        arr[$1]   += $4
        count[$1] += 1
    }
    END{
        for (a in arr) {
            print arr[a] / count[a]
        }
    }
' FILE
```

Comment: Please explain why a student's name is twice? and how assignments column should be dealt with? Please explain it more in your post and let us know.

Comment: Also please explain: do we need to take their individual line's percentage and then take average? In case you are having multiple lines with same Student's name.

Comment: We need to group by each student. Each student has marks for multiple assignments so need to calculate percentage and grade by grouping all assignments corresponding to each student.

@RavinderSingh13 , how do I sort the output by student name?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you simply want to get percentage of students which is mentioned by you by doing(total earned points divided by total possible points) then try following, though I am not sure why more than 1 student name is there or do we need to take their individual line's percentage and then take average? That question is covered in my comment.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  print "Name    Percent Letter"
}
FNR>1{
  per=($4/$5)*100
  if(per>=90 && per<=100)   { grade="A" }
  else if(per>=80 && per<90){ grade="B" }
  else if(per>=70 && per<80){ grade="C" }
  else if(per>=60 && per<70){ grade="D" }
  else if(per<60)           { grade="E" }
  print $1,per,grade
}'   Input_file
```

---

---

***EDIT:*** After understanding James sir's answer got to know that my guess may be correct and you may need total of all occurences of student names values and at last you need percentage etc, in that case try following and this should keep safe the ORDER of STUDENT names as per Input_file in output.

```
awk '
BEGIN{
  FS=","
  print "Name    Percent Letter"
}
FNR>1 && !student[$1]++{
  student_name[++count]=$1
}
FNR>1{
  student_possible_points[$1]+=$5
  student_total_points[$1]+=$4
}
END{
  for(j=1;j<=count;j++){
    per=(student_total_points[student_name[j]]/student_possible_points[student_name[j]])*100
    if(per>=90 && per<=100)   { grade="A" }
    else if(per>=80 && per<90){ grade="B" }
    else if(per>=70 && per<80){ grade="C" }
    else if(per>=60 && per<70){ grade="D" }
    else if(per<60)           { grade="E" }
    printf("%s %.02f %s\n",student_name[j],per,grade) | "sort -k1.1"
  }
}'  Input_file | column -t
```

Comment: ++ for the speed.

Comment: See my comment for my answer and don't look at the edit history. :D

Comment: I need the output sorted alphabetically by student name rather than student names appearing in the same sequence as it is there in the input file. How to do that?

Comment: @pikaraider, Please check my EDIT solution once, I have added logic for sorting the output and let me know then?

Comment: @RavinderSingh13 , if I put ```| sort -k1.1``` at the end of your solution or the other solution by James Brown, the header row is getting misplaced because of sorting. But the header "Name Percent Letter" should be the first row always.

Comment: @pikaraider, As I mentioned in my previous comment, if you see my EDIT, that has been taken care, you will NOT see any headers misplaced,let me know now?

Comment: it works fine now! i put the sort at the very end, that's why i faced that issue. but the output columns are not aligned properly. output is barely readable.

Comment: @pikaraider, ok, check my EDIT now, added `column -t` command now, let me know how it goes now?

Comment: works great! one small thing, how do I round off the percentage to 2 decimal places in your code. also, please look at my query in the other answer addressed to James. that's an issue i am facing with awk script.

Comment: @pikaraider, For 1 question 1 thread please, you could open a new question for same too, cheers.

Comment: Thanks a lot @RavinderSingh13

Comment: @pikaraider, Your welcome, cheers and happy learning on this great site SO.

Answer (score 3):

Another in awk. Pretty much the same as @ RavinderSingh13's but this one only examines the lower bound of the percentage (as the order of `else if`'s takes care of the upper bound):

```
$ awk '
BEGIN { FS="," }
NR>1 {
    tep[$1]+=$4
    tpp[$1]+=$5
}
END {
    print "Name\tPercent\tLetter"
    for(i in tep) {
        grade=100*tep[i]/tpp[i]
        if(grade>=90)
            letter="A"
        else if(grade>=80)
            letter="B"
        else if(grade>=70)
            letter="C"
        else if(grade>=60)
            letter="D"
        else 
            letter="E"                 # would ve expected F
        printf "%s\t%.2f\t%s\n",i,grade,letter
    }
}' file
Chelsey 82.86   B
Sam     50.50   E
```

Using tabs to separate fields in output so if you have names that exceed the tab width in chars, output will look nasty. In that case pipe the output to `column -t` for clean up:

```
$ awk ... | column -t
Name         Percent  Letter
Chelsey      82.86    B
Sammmmmmmmm  50.50    E
```