# How to print script so the calculated weighted grade for each student that appears in the data file

Tags: awk

How do I print my script so the calculated weighted grade for each student that appears in the data     file?
Down below I have formatted my script except the printing aspect.

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

$4~/[0-9]/ {

    EARN[STUDENT$2]+=$4
    POSSIBLE[STUDENT$2]+=$5
    STUDENTS[STUDENT]++
    CATEGORIES[$2]++
}
END {
 #      for (ASSIGNMENT in EARN) {
  #             print ASSIGNMENT,EARN[ASSIGNMENT]/POSSIBLE[ASSIGNMENT]
  #     }
    for (STUDENT in STUDENTS) {
           Homework=(EARN[STUDENT"Homework"]/POSSIBLE[STUDENT"Homework"])*0.10
           Lab=(EARN[STUDENT"Lab"])*0.30
           Quiz=(EARN[STUDENT"Quiz"]/POSSIBLE[STUDENT"Quiz"])*0.20
           Total=HOMEWORK+LAB+QUIZ
            LETTER="A"
            }
            if (TOTAL <= 90) {
                    LETTER="B"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 80) {
                    LETTER="C"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 70) {
                    LETTER="D"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 60){
                    LETTER="E"
            }

}
```

Comment: This is pretty similar, not sure if identical since no sample: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58290070/calculate-percentage-and-grade-from-input-file-in-awk/

Comment: @JamesBrown, woww nice memory, I really forget answers, if OP confirms this link helps op I will delete my answer and close this question as dup too cheers.

Comment: Don't use all upper case variable names so you avoid clashes with builtin variable names (and so people don't get a headache trying to read your code!)

Comment: Please provide a sample of input data.

Comment: A = 90 >= grade <= 100
B = 80 >= grade < 90
C = 70 >= grade < 80
D = 60 >= grade < 70
E = grade < 60

Comment: Don't add information in comments, [edit] your question to include all relevant information and that includes concise, testable sample input and expected output. [Your last question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58717249/1745001) got closed due to you not providing enough information in it for people to be able to help you, don't let the same happen to this one. See [ask] if that's not clear.

Comment: @Alex, IMHO you should see the link which JamesBrown sir has posted, looks like very similar to your query, please check it out once.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like you are running an `awk` code. Since you have not shown any samples so by seeing your code only I have made the edit of code. Added a line before last occurrence of `}` in code(see 2nd last line of this code) which will create an output file named `output_file` you could change it too as per you need).

```
BEGIN {
    FS=","
}

$4~/[0-9]/ {

    EARN[STUDENT$2]+=$4
    POSSIBLE[STUDENT$2]+=$5
    STUDENTS[STUDENT]++
    CATEGORIES[$2]++
}
END {
 #      for (ASSIGNMENT in EARN) {
  #             print ASSIGNMENT,EARN[ASSIGNMENT]/POSSIBLE[ASSIGNMENT]
  #     }
    for (STUDENT in STUDENTS) {
           Homework=(EARN[STUDENT"Homework"]/POSSIBLE[STUDENT"Homework"])*0.10
           Lab=(EARN[STUDENT"Lab"])*0.30
           Quiz=(EARN[STUDENT"Quiz"]/POSSIBLE[STUDENT"Quiz"])*0.20
           Total=HOMEWORK+LAB+QUIZ
            LETTER="A"
            }
            if (TOTAL <= 90) {
                    LETTER="B"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 80) {
                    LETTER="C"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 70) {
                    LETTER="D"
            }
            if (LETTER <= 60){
                    LETTER="E"
            }
            print STUDENT OFS LETTER > "output_file"
}
```

Comment: Andrew  75.21   C
Chelsey 92.21   A
Shane   77.64   C
Ava     79.76   C
Sam     62.34   D

That should be my output.

Comment: @Alex, Sorry your post is not clear, since no samples were given. As already mentioned by Ed sir you need to post samples clearly in your question. Since you only asked for taking output into Output file so I have added that part of code only.